# Replace all lines except first

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I trying do something like that for example:

```
<img src="/1.gif" />
<img src="/2.gif" />
<img src="/3.gif" />
<img src="/4.gif" />
<img src="/5.gif" />
```

And I want replace all lines contains `IMG` with "`---`" except first. I don't want delete it, just replace. 
I tried doing this with `preg_replace` but with no results.

Comment: Can you include the code that you tried?

Comment: are there lines with something else but img elements? can the lines contain more than one element? Please clarify the input format.

Comment: Are you using a javascript lib like jQuery?

Answer (score -1):

There is no point in doing this with RegEx, you should use an XML parser like this one: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php.

However, an even better approach in my oppinion is using client side technology for this.
I would use jQuery because it's the one I know best, but any is just as good, even JavaScript outside of a framework.

For jQuery it would be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#parent-of-images-id img:not(first)').replaceWith('<p>---</p>');
});
```

Comment: If you can post the code for the parent of the `<img/>` tags I can help with adapting the code. It doesn't have to be an ID of the parent, it can be a class or anything else that can describe an element in your markup.

Comment: Haha, you don't need jQuery to add two numbers in JS.